# How to unpack Inno Setup bundles with Arc+SREP data?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, unpacking, executable

I've stumbled upon Inno Setup installer with additional separate Arc archives (commonly with `.bin` extension) that I was unable to extract using normal methods:

1. the installer didn't work for an obscure reason (e.g.
   `Runtime Error (at -1:0): Cannot Import EXTRACTFILENAME.`),
2. extracting the Arc file with FreeArc was impossible due to `ERROR: unsupported compression method srep`,
3. also, the archive was apparently password-protected (trying to open it with FreeArc UI resulted in *Enter decryption password* dialog box).

How can one deal with such a situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three main steps here:

1. you'll have to decompile/dissect the IS installer itself; the easiest way is to use [Inno Setup Decompiler](https://vdisasm.com/isd/) ; essentially, you'll need to get `CompiledCode.bin` from your `.exe` file, and then disasm it, possibly finding a code that handles the unpacking - it usually calls `ISArcExtract` or a similar library function, and is placed in a method named `CURSTEPCHANGED`.
2. you have to get SREP (SuperREP) extractor (for more info, see e.g. http://krinkels.org/resources/superrep-srep.107/ and https://www.fileforums.com/showthread.php?p=460707) - the easiest way is to get a pack called `SrepInside0.33.7z` (available for download in various places), as it has all the required files bundled (essentially, you'll get an `unarc.exe` with `CLS-srep.dll` lib and `cls.ini` config).
3. in your Inno Setup's disassembly, locate the variable that holds the password itself (in case of `ISArcExtract` it's the 7th parameter passed), and pass it to your `unarc` call - note that it may contain non-printable characters (e.g. <32 ASCII codes), so that passing the password using a script is advisable.

Note that there are different versions/variants to both Arc and SREP; the above method should work in most cases, though.

Comment: Is there a way to user FreeArc to open those arc bins? I managed to open a few after fiddling with External compressor entries in arc.ini for srep, but others, some from more recent installers, give block descriptor is corrupted regardless. I know they're arcs, internal inno files have the unarc.dll.

Comment: @JasonXA AFAIR (I haven't done this in a year, and I don't have any relevant files handy), it's a version mismatch problem - FreeArc got abandoned ca. v0.666, with v0.67 roaming in the wild, some people having access to the v0.70, and there's also [FreeArc Next](https://github.com/Bulat-Ziganshin/FA) right now as the supported version. Try with the latest versions, YMMV.